# Running ".includes" on a url, by checking for the presence of a series of characters not working

Tags: javascript, string, angular, typescript

I am trying to conditionally populate some data to a route depending on whether or not the URL of that particular route has a certain prefix in my Angular 2 app. Assume a route like this:

> "http://localhost:4200/staff/e9a54desc2bea54l3"

To check for this, I am running this function from my routeService file:

```
  isRoomRoute(routeUrl) {
      if (this.url.includes('staff')) {
          console.log('This url: ' + routeUrl + ' is a roomRoute');
      } else {
          console.log('This url: ' + routeUrl + ' is NOT a room route');
      }
  }
```

And this is connected to my app.component (which is importing the routeService file and using it in the constructor), which is registering route changes, and then calling my "isRoomRoute" function, like this:

```
constructor(private routeService: RouteService,
            private router: Router) {

    this.router.events.subscribe((route) => {
    let routeUrl = route.url;
    this.routeService.sendRoute(routeUrl);
    this.routeService.isRoomRoute(routeUrl);
    });
}
```

Currently I am getting results that don't appear to fit the conditional parameters I am checking for. In other words, the function returns true or false in unexpected ways, that don't seem to depend on characters in a particular URL.

For instance, if I run this for this route:

> http://localhost:4200/staff/321e8a56ar6s

I get this result in the console:

> This url: /staff/321e8a56ar6s is NOT a room route

Clearly this is not the expected result, because according to the function logic, I should get a positive response that this IS a room result, because it contains "staff" in the evaluated url:

```
  isRoomRoute(routeUrl) {
      if (this.url.includes('staff')) {
          console.log('This url: ' + routeUrl + ' is a roomRoute');
      } else {
          console.log('This url: ' + routeUrl + ' is NOT a room route');
      }
  }
```

I know the URL is being passed, because it's part of the console log that I am seeing in the console. So what am I missing that's making this function not work as expected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `If` statement inside your `isRoomRoute` function is checking for `this.url` (routeService property?) instead of the `routeUrl` (passed url).

Comment: Ah, thank you! You're right, changing the function to this worked:

  isRoomRoute(routeUrl) {
      if (routeUrl.includes('crew')) {
          console.log('This url: ' + routeUrl + ' is a roomRoute');
      } else {
          console.log('This url: ' + routeUrl + ' is NOT a room route');
      }
  }